# (null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) when use admob

Tags: ios, admob

H, I use admob of google, I added all the framework, I did exactly what they wrote in the guidline. But after I build this error appeared . I went through some solution on stackoverflow but can not fix it please help me.

```
  "_CGSizeFromGADAdSize", referenced from:


      -[GADMasterViewController init] in GADMasterViewController.o


      -[GADMasterViewController resetAdView:] in GADMasterViewController.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in GADMasterViewController.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADInterstitial", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in GADMasterViewController.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in GADMasterViewController.o


  "_kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape", referenced from:


      -[GADMasterViewController resetAdView:] in GADMasterViewController.o


  "_kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait", referenced from:


      -[GADMasterViewController init] in GADMasterViewController.o


      -[GADMasterViewController resetAdView:] in GADMasterViewController.o


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to build your project for 64bit x86 architecture, hence the message: **"ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"**

I'm not sure exactly how do you do this, since you want to build an iOS project, and even if you would built it for the simulator, the architecture would be i386, not x86_64. Something is wrong with your build settings. Could you provide us with some details on these settings?

Comment: I just check my architecture, I dont know why it Switch to standard(include 64bit) after I debug. I switch it to normal and it ran. Thank you in advance :)